# How can I handle two exceptions differently (action 1 and 2), but if they occur together handle them with action 1?

Tags: python, exception

Let's say I have this piece of code in Python:

```
while True:
    try:
        raise CustomError

    except CustomError:
        # Action1

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Action2
```

I want whenever `CustomError` happens, Action1 handles it. But if and only if I have a `KeyboardInterruptError`, then Action2 happens (even though `CustomError` is still raised).
Now what happens in my code is `Action1` always happens and if user press CTRL+C , the code ignores it and still `Action1` occurs.

I would appreciate it if someone can help me with this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Only one exception can be raised at a time, so it's not clear what you mean by them happening together.

Comment: Is `customError` a subclass of `KeyboardInterrupt`?

Comment: @Barmar customError is in loop, so it will be raised anyway...and suddenly the user press Ctrl+C ... so two error are happening at the same time...

Comment: @mypetlion No it is not.

Comment: Everything is serialized by the Python interpreter -- the keyboard interrupt happens either before or after `raise CustomError`.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the loop. Raising the exception breaks out of the loop immediately.

Comment: What's probably happening is that the user doesn't press Ctl-C quickly enough, so `raise CustomError` has already occurred before `KeyboardInterrupt` is sent.

Comment: @Barmar sorry my bad! I edited the code now...I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense, and now I don't have a theory.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do about the timing; if `CustomError` is raised before you type Control-C, then `Action1` is at least going to begin. However, it looks like you want two `try` statements, one nested in the other:

```
try:
    try:
        raise CustomError
    except CustomError:
        Action1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    Action2
```

This ensures that the keyboard interrupt will be caught and handled whether it happens while control is in the inner `try` clause or in the `CustomError` handler.